# Bitmap image in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I was trying the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >     
    <mx:Canvas id="myBox">
        <mx:Box id="myBox2">
            <mx:Image source="img/hippo.bmp"></mx:Image>
            <mx:Image source="img/close_button.gif"></mx:Image>
        </mx:Box>
    </mx:Canvas>    
</mx:Application>
```

I got the image of close_button.gif while the other hippo.bmp is not displayed. What is the problem with bitmap file in Flex?

Comment: Why in god's name would you *ever* use a bmp?!?

Comment: Why Image Editors still supports for bmp?

Comment: So that archaic, unused, unpopular, and reviled formats (like bmp) can be converted to something that's actually good, like jpg or png for web purposes (since BMP has horrible compression and was never designed for web).

Comment: You really should consider converting that BMP to a better image format. Not only will it make it easier for you to use it in mxml but it will also reduce the size of your file which has a direct impact on the perceived speed of your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer:

1. Add the package to your project
2. Add an image container on the screen
3. `var image1:BmpReader=new BmpReader;`
4. `imageObjectOnScreen.addChild(image1.BmpReaderEx(“MyPicture.bmp”));`

You must definitely check [this](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=10264).

Comment: Thank you so much. The package is using flash.filesystem.*. filesystem is not available in my current environment. "filesystem " may be available in Adobe Air environment.

Answer (score 0):

Flex supports embedding JPEG, GIF, and PNG files. You can use these images for icons, skins, and other types of application assets.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html